# Meteor, Future and Node.JS net

Tags: node.js, meteor

I'm trying to write a simple asynchronous TCP/IP client that runs alongside a Meteor server for communicating to a remote server and posting data to MongoDB.  I got it working using net.on callbacks, but the code was messy and it was failing at random times.  I decided to try writing it using fibers/Futures to clean it up so I could focus on the failures.  The code currently looks like:

```
var Future = Npm.require('fibers/future'), wait = Future.wait;

var coreComm = function(coreClient) {
    console.log('coreCommm started')

    try {
        var running = true
        while (running) {
            console.log('calling onF.wait()')
            var ev = onF.wait();
            console.log('ev received', ev)
            switch(ev[0]) {
                default:
                    console.log('unknown event from coreClient: ', ev)
                    break;
                case 'readable':
                    console.log('read', ev)
                    break;
            }
        }
    } catch(err) {
        console.log('comm error: ', err)
    }

}.future()

function tryConnect(options) {
    var connect = new Future 
    onF = new Future

    coreClient = net.connect(options, function() {
        console.log('connected,')
        connect.return()
    })
    connect.wait()

    coreClient.on('readable', 
        function() { console.log('readable event,'); onF.return(['readable'])})
    console.log('coreClient connected to core');

    coreComm(coreClient)
}

Meteor.startup(function () {
    tryConnect({port: 9987});
}
```

The output when a message is sent looks like:

```
=> Meteor server running on: http://localhost:3000/
I2038-10:42:18.160(-5)? starting
I2038-10:42:18.392(-5)? connected,
I2038-10:42:18.398(-5)? coreClient connected to core
I2038-10:42:18.402(-5)? coreCommm started
I2038-10:42:18.409(-5)? calling onF.wait()
I2038-10:42:18.413(-5)? readable event,
```

As far as I can tell, the message is received from the remote server, the readable event is sent, I call onF.return(...) and nothing happens except Meteor goes to 100% CPU.

Any suggestions as to why the onF.wait() call isn't returning like it's suppose to?

Comment: I needed to do something like this and just used celery + rabbitMQ.  I know this isn't any help to fix your code but maybe will help you avoid some work/solve your problem in another way.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you might use the node-ddp-client to push data into the Meteor server -- you preserve the realtime (at least until the oplog tailing branch of Meteor is merged).